# Thread.join() (instance method)

Tags: java, multithreading, join

Why is it not possible to `.join()` before starting a thread? Should not be implicit that if I call join() on a thread even if not started previously should be started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `join()` waits for a thread to die as the Javadoc say; it cannot die if it hasn't started yet.

I do not think it should start a thread if it is not started because the method would do two things: start a thread and wait for the thread, which is bad design.

Comment: Yes something that does not exist yet is not worth waiting for.

Answer (score 2):

Acorrding to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. If `t` is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,

```
t.join();
```

causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread terminates. Overloads of join allow the programmer to specify a waiting period.

> SO it clearly tells that if you join a thread then the current thread
>   will wait until the termination of thread. So if a thread is not
>   started yet how can it be terminated.

**Proof By Contradiction :D**

say you can join a thread `t` without starting. then you call

```
t.join();
```

now as per the behavior of join current thread will be waiting. Now say some evil thinking (!) comes to your mind and you haven't started the thread (:D). What will be happened now? Imagine this scenario and you will find your answer